# Eclipse IDE within docker

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, docker, docker-machine

I do dev on a Windows machine and using docker via docker-machine. Due to help from @VonC was able to achieve [folder share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934776/share-windows-folder-other-than-c-users-with-docker-container-using-docker-w/33935328) from windows dev folder to docker container.

The IDE I would like to use for Java development is Eclipse. But I would not like to install the whole java system on my host machine. And since my host machine is Windows (not an X system), can't use the X11 socket sharing stuff as mentioned [here](http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/)  to install Eclipse into the container where Java resides.

So, if my code resides in my host machine and whole java subsystem is within the docker container, would Eclipse be able to build the code? Has anyone working on a non-Linux (preferably Windows) host got Eclipse IDE to build java applications using a java docker image to hold all things java.

Comment: Have you tried using VNC? I know the Selenium docker debug images allow you to observe test runs using VNC on Windows.

Comment: [docker - Is it possible to install Visual Studio in a Windows Container - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41459500/233637)
May be an answer.

Comment: And why can't you use the "socket stuff"? Have a look at X-forwarding through ssh using putty and Xming. This way you can run any graphical application from any network-connected linux machine on your windows machine (including a docker container)

Comment: You can run X window on windows, there are several options https://superuser.com/questions/99303/what-are-my-x-client-options-for-ms-windows

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this behavior by using eclipse che:

https://hub.docker.com/r/eclipse/che/

> Eclipse Che is a next-generation cloud IDE and workspace server that can run anywhere Docker runs.

By the way, it runs in a browser.

Another alternative is cloud9: https://docs.c9.io/docs/.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at https://github.com/fgrehm/docker-eclipse (authored by the same person as blog post)

Even when it is possible someone should care about making new images for every Eclipse version.

And I have just raised issue "run on Windows" #7
https://github.com/fgrehm/docker-eclipse/issues/7

Also see https://rgrunber.wordpress.com/2016/01/26/eclipse-inside-a-docker-container/ about using VNC

Comment: One could try to install some windows X Server like for example [vcxsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) and set the `DISPLAY` using TCP ... might need some more specific details, but maybe it can be enough.

Comment: This repository has been archived by the owner on Jun 12, 2018.

Answer (score 2):

I'm almost sure that there is no way (yet?) to run graphical applications within a Docker on a Windows host.

However you could still compile inside the docker (with the Java eco-system) and run Eclipse (or any other IDE) from your windows, by using volumes. But Java is embedded by Eclipse if I'm right... So I don't know what IDE you could use and not sure how to get all their features (IDE usually compile at every line you write to show compilation error graphically).

Anyway... My point is that you can use any IDE you like to edit your code, and any compiler you like (or even ANT, or MAVEN or ..) to compile inside a Docker.

Comment: The intellisense, real-time code compilation, etc are the reasons I would want to use an IDE like Eclipse. Otherwise I could just use an editor like Sublime, Notepad++, etc to just write code and compile/run from within docker.

Comment: Then you _do_ need to run this IDE within the Docker but I can't see a way of running GUI app from Windows host...

Comment: [docker - Is it possible to install Visual Studio in a Windows Container - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41459500/233637) It comes.

Comment: @tech_me here it is for VSCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/05/02/remote-development

Comment: to be clear you can run gui applications inside docker on windows. You need to set up x11 forwarding. I used this to install oracle database in docker which has a gui setup step. I installed VcXsrv on the windows host and had to install few packages in the linux guest. Also have to ensure "DISPLAY=<myNetworkCartdIp>:0.0" variable is set in linux guest. Find the ip using ipconfig command in windows. I had to try different ones since I have like 10 NICs but finally found it. https://www.techoism.com/configure-x11-forwarding-centosrhel-67/

Answer (score -1):

You can install native w32 eclipse, and run the builds from within docker as the answer on [Eclipse - Docker integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655766/eclipse-docker-integration) explains